# Remove and restore stickers from back of laptop

Tags: technology

I have a dozen stickers from hackathons on my laptop that I want to save. I am switching laptops and want to save them and put them on my new laptop.  Anyone know a way I can do this?  Even removing them and regluing them will work.

Thanks :)

Some pictures:

[image: Laptop 1]
[image: Laptop 2]
[image: Laptop 3]
[image: Laptop 4]

Comment: if they aren't something special like "holograms", you could just scan them (putting the laptop on the scanner), and then print new stickers from that scanned image

Comment: what is the material of the stickers? can you provide a photo? thanks. depending on the material sarge's answer might be the best. or asking the organizer's for the csv / psd / png file instead of scaning.

Comment: Will do, I'd prefer to keep them being the original. Although, I could always do that as a backup in case I break them.

Comment: Get the teflon tool from AvE that youtube guy (or build one yourself)

Comment: It is for this reason that I like getting laptops that are business class like the Dell Latitudes were precisions, because then in a couple years when I'm looking to upgrade I can just get a replacement LCD back cover off eBay for $20 to $50 and swap it out and keep my sticker laden trophy as a decoration for my office.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since most of them are made of a semi-plastic material, the safest way is by using a hairdryer. Start heating from the corners of the sticker.
Apply heat for 45 seconds and try to peel it. If it's coming off smoothly, keep going; if not, apply another 45 seconds of heat.

Rinse and repeat and they'll be off!

Soaking them a little could help the process, but being a laptop, water might not be a good thing to put near it, so use nail polish remover instead (a non-flammable one). Olive oil (actually any type of greasy oil) can help remove the glue after the sticker is off.

Comment: is there something where olive oil cannot help? :D

Comment: WARNING: Don't actually rinse and repeat. just in case.

Comment: Also I use 75% Alcohol to dissolve the glue.

Comment: nail polish remover sometimes may damage the plastic

Comment: There's also a product called "Goo Gone" that's essentially vegetable oil plus orange oil. Removes sticker adhesive like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be heating them up with a hairdryer, and then using a razorblade or a very sharp knife to peel them off.

Solvents like rubbig alcohol or nail polish remover might work, but I would recommend against them, as they can dissolve some dyes and plastics.

Answer (score 1):

I used to work the service desk at Kohl's. When items too large to fit into a bag were purchased, we'd attach a large sticker to the item at checkout so security could know it wasn't stolen. At the service desk we had a special spray for when those items were returned - spray it liberally onto the sticker, wait 5-10 minutes, then the sticker would easily peel off, without taking the top layer of the box with it (thus preserving the "new" look of the packaging). If we didn't use enough, or if we waited too long/not long enough, it was less effective. The stickers, after being removed and allowed to dry, could have been reused (though we didn't do so, for lack of a place to keep them nor sufficient need).

Unfortunately, I don't remember what the product was called, but I think something like this might work, as long as you remove the stickers carefully, and then let them dry before applying them to the new laptop.